# How to order two timestamp columns, showing timestamp A in desc order first, the rest by ID in desc order, last timestamp B in desc order

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

My table has two columns both timestamps.

**Column A** is called `featured_at`.
Default value is NULL. If item is not featured, it is NULL. When featured, the value is a future timestamp of which it will expire.

**Column B** is called `sold`.
Default value is NULL. Items that are not sold is NULL. When marked as sold, the value is a timestamp of when it was marked as sold.

What I want to accomplish is display all items:

- Sorted by the latest `featured_at` timestamp first
- Followed by the rest of regular items sorted by their ID in descending order
- And lastly, the sold items in descending order being shown at the very last.

Here's my query so far:

```
$items = Item::where('status', 'Active')
            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->orderByDesc('featured_at')
            ->orderBy('sold','desc')
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate(12);
```

Comment: "the sold items in descending order being shown at the very last" - you mean the ones where sold is null?

Comment: sold items have timestamps on their value. descending order means, ones that are sold the latest comes first, but they are the last priority shown last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry late reply. I managed to solved this using the following query.

```
$items = Item::where('status', 'Active')
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->orderByRaw('featured_at IS NULL, featured_at DESC, sold IS NOT NULL, sold DESC, id DESC')
        ->paginate(12);
```

Items are finally sorted in this order.

1. Featured items sorted by date in desc order
2. Regular items sorted by ID in desc order
3. Sold items sorted by date in desc order

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort items with `NULL` last we can use `orderByRaw`

```php
$items = Item::where('status', 'Active')
            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(featured_at), featured_at DESC')
            ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(sold), sold DESC')
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate(12);
```

Comment: I tried, still showing the sold as the first ones.

Comment: can you give an example of what you get now vs the order you want to achive?